# USA apartment rent application: is it legal to require employment?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, discrimination, tenant, rent

When applying to rent an apartment in any state of the USA, is there any federal regulation that prevents the landlord from requiring the applicant to provide a proof of past/present **employment**, while rejecting any other proof of **income**, e.g. proving sufficient savings by providing recent bank statements?

Comment: If you narrowed the question down to a particular state, you can expect a better answer.

Comment: Income from sources other than regular employment are likely considered more volatile by the landlord. Without touching the legal aspects, perhaps they would accept some form of trust set up for the purposes of rent payment, proof of sufficiently high savings (20-30x monthly rent), or you could look into getting a guarantor.

Answer (score -1):

Prevents? No. Even the poorest of Families need to provide proof of income. For reasons below.

*When dealing with Residential Screening:*

If the Property Requires it you would need to Provide your Social.
Most of the process is checking background. Which includes your Credit and Criminal Background.

Low Credit would require a proof of income. As well as Stabilized and Affordable Housing. In order to obtain Credit from the State, the Property Management Company needs to prove the Resident cannot afford their Unit.

If you have good Credit then, most likely you will not be required to prove income. If you get flagged for Employment issues like gaps in Employment i.e.: Not having a job because you have wealthy Family, Inheritance or even too many unemployment Claims, etc. etc. You would need official Bank Statements to prove you indeed have suitable income.

Otherwise Companies like Jetty and Rhino can insure/bond the Tenant by holding them liable for Rent and Deposit while the Landlord can accept an application and allow Move-in. Since, either way the Property Management Company will get their Money.

Comment: The OP is not asking about "proof of income", but "proof of employment".  If I have a trust fund that reliably gives me $10,000/month, I have plenty of income - but (probably) no employment.

Comment: I went over Employment in paragraph 2 a little. It's a lower tier subject when applying. I work as Software Analyst for Property Management software. Just laying out how screening works and they really don't go over the Tenants Employer when Screening. It's rare you get a Property that needs to know you have a job. Mostly, "if you DONT have one; can you afford to live here?". If you default on the Apartment and they need to garnish wages in the Lawsuit they'll deal with it then.

Comment: I think the OP is asking "can I, as a landlord, insist that the tenant be employed?".  Also your answer refers to "the poorest of families" - they are the least likely to be able to afford the rent without employment. (Not the down-voter by the way.)